# How to remove title space from menu item list in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I want to remove title space from my menu item list. I want to only display icon in the menu list but there are many extra space in the list. How can I remove that space from the menu list?

Anyone has idea related to this then please share with me.

I am stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some screenshot and/or xml will be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom actionbar by using layout.

```
private void init() throws NotFoundException {

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.header_bg));
}
```